# Upload cropped image using jQuery Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image that has been cropped by icrop.js but am not good with JQuery & Ajax.How can I grab the image from the result and send it to a folder on the server?

```
<form id="form" action="upload.php" method="post" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <img id="result">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#file").change(function(e){
    var img = e.target.files[0];
    if(!iEdit.open(img, true, function(res){
        $("#result").attr("src", res);          
    })){
        alert("Whoops! That is not an image!");
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

When the image is cropped its placed in the image tag with id="result". This is what I need sent to the server.

Comment: How exactly you want to send it to the server using jQuery AJAX or just default HTML form submit?

Comment: Either will do for me. My problem is grabbing the image and sending it to the server when its not exactly "input" tagged.